# Postgresql is not running on localhost

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-14.04

I recently installed postgresql on my ubuntu 14.04 vm, but I can't seem to be able to connect to my database from localhost: `postgres://127.0.0.1:5432/mydb?sslmode=disable` is not found, although `psql mydb` brings me to the correct terminal, `sudo netstat -plunt |grep postgres` returns nothing, but `su postgres -c "netstat -plunt |grep postgres"` prints:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      31/postgres
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5432                :::*                    LISTEN      31/postgres
```

So it's clearly there, just somehow under the postgres ubuntu user (but with the database belonging to root). I know that there is a way to reconfigure my postgresql installation such that it can be reached through localhost (`postgres://127.0.0.1:5432/mydb?sslmode=disable` works), and if anyone could tell me what I need to do, that would be awesome. Thank you!

Comment: hopefully you not just put this to your browser address bar?..